# SearchView adding wrong item from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i'm trying to add a SearchView in my RecyclerView that will permise to search different kind of items on it,

But i'm getting a problem when i'm searching for one result in SearchView and it has been found when i click on it the selected item is wrong or better it's ever the item from main ArrayList and not searched result as you can see in the gif below i'm searching for Bayles when i press on it snackbar saying that i've selected Bayles but when i add it as child item to another recyclerView it has added ABBONDANTE and not Bayles.

[image]

Here is my ViewHolder from the Adapter

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                        Snackbar.make(v,variantiConstructors.get(position).getDeskT(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

While here is my onClickListener from the Activity where i add the item to other RecyclerView

```
   adapterVarianti.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterVarianti.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {

                search.clearFocus();

                if (dummyDataItems.size() != 0) {

                    if (tipo.toString().equals("CON ") || tipo.toString().equals("PIU' ") || tipo.toString().equals("MENO ") || tipo.toString().equals("SENZA ")) {

// Here i'm adding the selected item to a String builder but i think it's here where i'm doing something wrong

                        tipo.append(filteredVariable.get(position).getDeskT());

// Adding item from the recyclerView where there is searchView to last item from the recyclerView on background.

                        ItemPTERM lastAdded = dummyDataItems.get(dummyDataItems.size() - 1);
                        lastAdded.setVariant(new Variant(tipo.toString()));

                        if (exampleAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                            mRecyclerViewTOP.scrollToPosition(exampleAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                        }
                        exampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        tipo = new StringBuilder();

                        if(segmentedButtonGroup.getPosition() == 0){
                            tipo = new StringBuilder();
                            tipo.append("CON ");
                        }
                        if(segmentedButtonGroup.getPosition() == 1){
                            tipo = new StringBuilder();
                            tipo.append("PIU' ");
                        }
                        if(segmentedButtonGroup.getPosition() == 2){
                            tipo = new StringBuilder();
                            tipo.append("MENO ");
                        }
                        if(segmentedButtonGroup.getPosition() == 3){
                            tipo = new StringBuilder();
                            tipo.append("SENZA ");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my Adapter code with filter

```
public class AdapterVarianti extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder>  implements Filterable {


    private ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> variantiConstructors;
    private ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> mFilteredList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface  OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.varianti_recycler,parent,false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
    }

    AdapterVarianti(ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> exampleList){
        variantiConstructors = exampleList;
        mFilteredList = variantiConstructors;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterVarianti.ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final VariantiConstructor item = variantiConstructors.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getDeskT());
        holder.prepiu.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
        holder.premeno.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPacq()));

        if(position % 2 == 0 ){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17e1a0"));

        }else if(position % 2 == 1){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7EC0EE"));
        }

    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (mFilteredList == null)
                    mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>(variantiConstructors);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (mFilteredList != null && mFilteredList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final VariantiConstructor cd : mFilteredList) {
                            if (cd.getDeskT().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size(); //newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = mFilteredList;
                    oReturn.count = mFilteredList.size(); //newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                variantiConstructors = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<VariantiConstructor>) results.values);
                // FIXME: 8/16/2017 implement Comparable with sort below
                ///Collections.sort(itemList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return variantiConstructors.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView prepiu;
        public TextView premeno;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            prepiu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PrePiu);
            premeno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PreMeno);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                            Snackbar.make(v,variantiConstructors.get(position).getDeskT(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you hide item while searching?

Comment: @TruongHieu i use Filter, added my full Adapter code

Comment: @TruongHieu i'm almost sure that the issue is what i'm using filteredVariable.get(position).getDeskT() in my Activity while i should pass the filtered ArrayList from the Adapter because my "filteredVariable" is the ArrayList with all items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by passing again the list to Activity by the following code:

```
public ArrayList<VariantiConstructor> getList(){
    return variantiConstructors;
}
```

And by this in activity code :

```
 tipo.append(adapterVarianti.getList().get(position).getDeskT());
```